# Wordpress include local Jquery Issue

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

Can anyone explain me with example what does the below lines means? (I am developing a wordpress plugin)

> You still have a copy of jquery UI and jquery in the JS folder.
>
> And you're still calling it:
>
> `wp_register_script( 'sa_jquery_ui', plugins_url('/js/jquery-ui.js', __FILE__) );`

I am stuck

Comment: where did you put the `wp_register_script( 'sa_jquery_ui', plugins_url('/js/jquery-ui.js', FILE) );` statement? in which function of which file?

Comment: inside a function action "admin_init"

Comment: please, share the content of that function, so we can understand how are you handling the scripts registration process

Answer (score 1):

With wp_register_script you include your js-script in the plugin.

"Hey Wordpress! You must include this script when verificate and call my plugin" :)

This is like wp_register_* when you create a wordpress theme

Comment: lets put it this way, i have y own jquery.js, and jquery-ui.js, what is the best way to include those local files as wordpress  has its own jquery. say, i deleted y local jquery files and want to use what WordPress has. How do i do that

Answer (score 1):

> Try This Code In your Plugin main file

```
function pluging_enqueue_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'sa_jquery_ui', plugins_url('plugin-name/js/jquery-ui.js'), array(), '1.0.0', true );
 }
add_action( 'init', 'plugin_enqueue_script' );
```